# How to filter the duplicate data from JQGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid with data of different companies and with dates. There is the possibility that one company may appear multiple times with different dates. When a user clicks on "MostRecentOnly" Check box ,the grid should be filtered with Most recent date for each company. Can any one please help me how to do it on the client side.

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this would be on the server-side, where you can easily make a SQL query to retrieve the data in question.

It will be more difficult on the client side. I would suggest extracting data from the grid using [`getGridParam`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) and the [`data`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) option, saving that data, and creating a filtered copy that you load back into the grid.